# Octave or python for implementing Machine Learning

Tags: python, matlab, octave

When is the need to learn octave or Mat Lab for Machine Learning? Are these required if you are proficient in python?

Comment: General answer: no you don't need any specific software/language/framework to do ML. Knowing several can help but it's a matter of personal preference and/or requirements for a job for example.